# explode using foreach inside codeigniter model not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a code which separate `,` from the string using explode.

Now the problem is the `foreach` loop only iterating once. Am using this code in `codeigniter model`.

My code is,

```
//Model

        $product_id = '1,2,3';
        $products = explode(',', $product_id);

        foreach($products as $products_id) {
            echo $products_id.'<br><br>'; //output: 1
            $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE products_id = "'.$products_id.'" AND products_status = "1"');
            $count = $query->num_rows();

            if($count > 0) {
                return $result = $query->result_array();
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

The output for the above code is `1`.

The other digit `2` and `3` is missing. Am I doing anything wrong. Please help me out. I can't figure it out.

Comment: Did you want get return all result of 1,2,3

Comment: Because you `return`. Returns ends the current function then and there.

Comment: your logic is flawed `} else { return 0;}` will exit the loop on the first iteration.  You return with more then 0 results or 0 results.

Comment: whether I want to place the `if else` condition outside `foreach`?

Comment: @KumarRakesh : yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correct it, you could do this

```
    $product_id = '1,2,3';
    $products = explode(',', $product_id);
    $data = [];

    foreach($products as $products_id) {
        echo $products_id.'<br><br>'; //output: 1
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE products_id = "'.$products_id.'" AND products_status = "1"');
        $count = $query->num_rows();

        if($count > 0) {
            $data = array_merge($data, $query->result_array());
        }
    }

    if(empty($data)){
        return 0;
    } 
    return $data;
```

Which avoids exiting in the original if statement you return on more then 0 results or 0 results, so basically on the first iteration of the loop.

But, that said, possibly a better way to fix it is this

```
  $product_id = '1,2,3';

  $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE products_id IN( ? ) AND products_status = "1"',$product_id);
  $count = $query->num_rows();

  if($count > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
  }else{
        return 0;
  }
```

Using IN you can avoid the `foreach`,`explode` and additional query calls, also you should use prepared queries.  This should work with numbers, but strings still need to be wrapped in quotes,  `'IN( "string","string", "string" )'` or `$string = '"string","string","string"';` as the input, which may complicate things for prepared queries.

Comment: just replace `array_merge($data, $query->result_array);` to `array_merge($data, $query->result_array());`

Comment: I would use IN instead, much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Everthing is fine in your code .If you want get all data , Then you should return  all in array .  check the code :

```
 $product_id = '1,2,3';
        $products = explode(',', $product_id);
$data = array();

        foreach($products as $products_id) {
            echo $products_id.'<br><br>'; //output: 1
            $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE products_id = "'.$products_id.'" AND products_status = "1"');
            $count = $query->num_rows();

            if($count > 0) {
                $data[]= $query->result_array();
            }
            else {
                 $data[]= 0;
            }
        }
return $data;
```

On `$data` .. You can do any action with $data as like you want.